# The name 'BurstTargetCpu' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the unity version 2021.2.3f1 and installed ml-agent released 15 version. The installation has been done without any error, new project is running without any issue.

Recently, I opened a unity project (the project is created on Mac) in my windows. I am getting errors while running the project.

**This one is the first error**

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0\Runtime\Editor\BurstReflection.cs(17,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BurstCompilerOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**and this one is the last error**

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0\Runtime\Intrinsics\Arm\NEON_AArch64.cs(7552,29): error CS0103: The name 'BurstTargetCpu' does not exist in the current context
```

In total, I'm getting 127 errors. Please have a look and do let me know how can I solve these errors. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Gjg.png)

Comment: What has the first paragraph to do with the second?

Comment: Just an information about unity and ml agent version.

Comment: It's possible the project you are using is incompatible with the Unity version installed?

Comment: The version is alright i guess, my colleague is working on the same in his own apple system.

Comment: Did you by chance copy the **Library** folder and/or add it to source control then transferred to your computer from the Mac?  You should not do that.  Close Unity, delete the **Library** folder and re-open the project.  Remove the **Library** folder from source control. 
 https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html